# how to start a service when application is closed

Tags: android, service

i want to start the service when the application is closed.

java code

```
public class AudioRecorder extends Service {
    public static final String SENDER_ID = "274211616343";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    }
```

Comment: What event do you want to do it for? - discribe your case, please.

Comment: i want to start the service when the application closed by the server side data recieved in the application

Answer (score 1):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver`. Let it start your `Service`.

Comment: how can i use it?

Comment: Although correct, starting from android O, starting a service when app is not running will throw exceptions, i sincerely suggest moving your functionality to a JobScheduler as the restrictions apply to all apps even if they don't target O

Comment: Actually you can still use Service, yet a JobIntentService. https://medium.com/@berriz_/service-and-boot-completed-on-android-o-6a389eae50f1

Comment: @jasmin it's a common knowledge, you can find many tutorials and guides if you search for it on Google.

Answer (score 0):

You've written in comment: "i want to start the service when the application closed by the server side data recieved in the application"

In this case why do not you use AlarmManager like this (it's a Kotlin):

```
private fun startServiceAndExit() {
    val startService = Intent(appContext, YourService::class.java)
    val pendingIntentId = 123456
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        appContext, 
        pendingIntentId, 
        intent, 
        0);  

    val mgr = appContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, pendingIntent)
    System.exit(0)
}
```